# How to prevent group footer on last page in birt

Tags: report, master-pages, footer, birt, page-numbering

Is there a way to prevent group footer on last page in birt? I want a label to be printed on every page but I don't want this label to be printed on last page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=215231), and it is [discussed here](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php/topic/21423-conditional-visibility-block-on-last-page/) that the "pageNumber" and the "totalPage" variables evaluated on the master page are always 1. So until this bug is fixed I thik there is no way to achieve this.

Otherwise you would act like this:
Go to your masterpage, select your item in the footer and select "visibility" in the Properties. Check "Hide Element" and add the following Expression:

```
if(pageNumber == totalPage) {
  true
} else {
  false
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes you are right after a while I read that it was bug, but I solved the problem with the same solution that you told. Yes it can be a solution of my problem for now. Thanks again...